# Can't see project in Source Control Explorer

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, source-control-explorer

I'm trying to download my project from Visual Studio Online (TFS), but I can't see one project in list. I have two accounts, main and secondary. I'm trying to get project using secondary account. Both users have Administrator permission on this project. Also, other projects, that I see in list, have same permissions with this account. I see this project on web-site (my_organization.visualstudio.com), but it is not in Visual Studio, in Source Control Explorer. Need some help - is there any bug, or I'm doing something wrong..? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is mainly handling issues’ open forum while your current question is organization identity/account issue targeting to Azure DevOps, which need assistance of the product group. Thus the best contact channel is here: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=21, the product support engineer will then contact the product group and offer efficient assistance. Thanks for your understanding.

BTW, you could refer to this doc: [Set repository permissions for Git or TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops-2020) to check your account's repository permissions in this project.